# Could prisoners be pardoned in 1832 France under the July Monarchy?

Tags: france, law, modern

For instance, could inspector Javert in "Les Miserables" have avoided his dilemma by asking for Jean Valjean to be pardoned by the French king and/or government?

Would the king and/or government have had that power in 1832 France?

#### Javert's Dilemma

> Javert [...] is caught between his
>   strict belief in the law and the mercy Valjean has shown him. He feels
>   he can no longer give Valjean up to the authorities but also cannot
>   ignore his duty to the law. Unable to cope with this dilemma, Javert
>   commits suicide by throwing himself into the Seine.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables)

Comment: I'm confused if this is on topic, however it adds a lot of context in a single (first) sentence.

Comment: Please revise the question to make it clear who the individuals are, when they lived and what government ruled France.

Comment: I took the liberty to add a quote from wiki to explain the dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. France's Head of State traditionally has had the power to pardon.

It was abolished for a short while during the Revolution, only to be reintroduced during the Consulate a few years later.

[https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grâce_(droit_français)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%A2ce_(droit_fran%C3%A7ais)) (in French)

Comment: It was nonetheless very rare